# Backspace and space not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp, firefox, gecko

I have the following validation to allow only numbers and a decimal in Javascript

```
function validate(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;           
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );
      var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
      if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
}
```

I call this in my textbox element like `onkeypress='validate(event)'`

This code works fine in IE but when I try the same with Firefox backspace, left and right arrow keys and space does not work.

How would I fix this?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you mean pressing those keys has no effect and you think it should or that pressing those keys has an effect and you think it shouldn't?

Comment: Well, here you can use Jquery's event.which property.
The event.which property returns which keyboard key or mouse button was pressed for the event.
So, only write theEvent.which in your code and backspace and space will work in Firefox.
Hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using key press is the right solution, but you simply need to attach the event handler by JS (which is considered better practice anyway), and use something like this:

```
$('#myInput').keypress(function(event){
   validate(event)
});

function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;           
  if (key <48 || key > 57  || key == 190)//keycode is a number between 0 and 9 or '.'
       ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use `keyup` or `keydown` instead of `keypress`

`keypress` is only supposed to fire when there is a character insert

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: Even, when I use onkeydown, backspace, left and right arrows does not work. Along with that decimal too does not work.

Answer (score 0):

keydown function would work across all browsers. Please use keydown function and it would work!

Ex.:-

```
$(document).keydown(function (e){
                    if(e.keyCode == 37) // left arrow
                    {

                    //code for left arrow

                    }
                    else if(e.keyCode == 39)    // right arrow
                    {

                   //code for right arrow
                    }
                    });
```

Comment: I only want backspace, left and right arrow to work as they are expected to

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    //allows number and hyphen only 
    function isNumeric(e)
    {
        var a = e.charCode;
        if(a==0){return;}
        return ((a >= 48 && a <= 57));
    }
    </script>
```

Firefox Backspace charcode 0.